# Создается файл .eslintcache после установки CRA

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, create-react-app, eslint

Игрался с webpack, устанавливал пакеты, в том числе eslint, и теперь, когда скачиваю CRA, то при каждом обновлении приложения появляется файл .eslintcache. Как устранить данную проблему?

Answer (score 1):

Этот файл создается с помощью react-scripts 4.0.1. Если изменить версию на 4.0.0, то эта проблема исчезает. Я думаю, в будущем это будет изменено.